# Dynamically fetch user Access token of Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have written an article [Upload photos to Facebook Fan Page using PHP](http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/upload-photos-to-facebook-fan-page.html). The code works fine but has only one problem. The **user** access token of the Facebook application is hard coded. See following line in the code:

```
//It can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
$access_token = '<Your access token>';
```

I cannot find anyway to dynamically fetch this **user** access token through PHP. ANy help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if you have to dynamically generate accesstoken for each user, you need to take permissions dynamically,
please check this page: [Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), do carefully look at manage_pages permission, also do look at the access_token terminology

then you would get the permission to manage the page by generating this login url by which users would login to your pageapp:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'manage_pages','redirect_uri'=>'http://you app pages link'));
```

here, in scope you should put 'manage_pages' and other permissions you need,then you should get your access_token by,

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: It doesn't give the 'USER' access token found at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token

Comment: It should do so long as the user has granted your app the appropriate permissions. Have you even tried it or just compared the 2? A user access token isn't generated once and remains the same either. It changes most likely with timestamps, especially as they become invalidated over time, that's why there could be a difference,either that or they're for different applications. Besides, if you are using the php-sdk, you don't need to supply the user access token with the $facebook-api(); It's only if you want to use a page_access token or the app access token that you need to supply it

Comment: Arvind07, the page you linked _does not_ provide _user_ access tokens, but __page__ access tokens (and app access tokens as well, but you’re looking for page access tokens). How to obtain them, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/